# Persisting composite pojo in hibernate but inner pojo getting freshly persisted

Tags: spring, hibernate

The situation is : I have a Pojo DEVICE, which has a pojo Namespace pojo inside. :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "device")
public class Device implements java.io.Serializable {

private long deviceId;
private long timestamp;
private NamespaceMaster namespaceMaster;
..................

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "namespace_id")
@Cascade(value = CascadeType.ALL)
public NamespaceMaster getNamespaceMaster() {
    return this.namespaceMaster;
}
```

When i am persisting Device, I am querying database to find the appropriate namespace and then setting the namespace pojo to device. Up to this part there is no isse.

```
NamespaceMaster namespaceMaster=null;
    try {
        namespaceMaster = namespaceDAOImpl.queryAllByName(namespace, AZURE_CLOUDTYPE).get(0);
    } catch (DaoException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    LOG.info("Namespace object from cache :{}",namespaceMaster);
    device.setNamespaceMaster(namespaceMaster);
```

Now when am trying persist Device, the namespace table in DB also has new row inserted with the same value that I initially queried namespace table. This is happening due to

```
@Cascade(value = CascadeType.ALL)
```

The reason is : Hibernate is unable to recognise the namespace object as already persisted one. So it cascades all the pojo inside and hense inserts a new one.

My question is simple. How to insert device object in table such that the namespace is not generated new. It is the one that is already present in namespace table. I tried removing @Cascade(value = CascadeType.ALL), but then i get a error :

```
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing
```

**Note**

I have added @version in NamespaceMaster table

```
@Version
private Long version;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

I am struck guys!! Please suggest.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the above issue.

I had inserted namespace_id(primary key for namespace table) as 0 for my data. May be hibernate is unable to understand 0 as the key and resolve in this situation. Guys be aware of this fact!!

I tried giving implementation for hashcode(),equals;@Version etc but nothing worked. updating my table primary key from 0 to a higher value worked!!

Anyways!!